# Windows 10 Hyper-V, how to completely uninstall, reset all settings

Tags: windows-10, hyper-v

Running Windows 10 Pro, v1803 OS 17134.648, 64-bit.

I am having a problem with machines that I've previously installed into Hyper-V.  I have successfully uninstalled Hyper-V, and have manually removed all vEthernet related NICs.  From previous experience of going through this process, if I reinstall Hyper-V, it will remember a number of settings from the previous install, including but not limited to the VMs I had installed (which I have exported to a different location.)

What I want to do now that Hyper-V is uninstalled is to do a clean sweep of all settings.  Find registry keys and delete them or reset them to the values they were at when I first enabled the Hyper-V feature.  Same with any .vhd*, .avhd*, .xml, etc. files.

I need to get Hyper-V to a state where a new Quick Create VM from a clean (not imported) source runs clean (no boot issues), then I can look to import my exported VMs.

These are the (unsuccessful) steps I have taken so far in an attempt to reset everything back to "factory":

- Uninstall Hyper-V using Windows Features
- [Reboot]
- Rename C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Hyper-V folder
- Rename C:\Users\Public\Documents\Hyper-V folder, if it exists
- Rename C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Event Viewer\Applications and Services Logs\Microsoft\Windows\Hyper-V-Hypervisor, if it exists
- Rename C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Event Viewer\Applications and Services Logs\Microsoft\Windows\Hyper-V-Worker, if it exists
- Rename C:\Users[logged_in_user]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Hyper-V
- In Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Network Connections

  - (Right-click Start icon, select Network Connections.  Select Ethernet in the left navigation bar, then Change Adapter Options)
  - right-click on "vEtnernet (Default Switch)", Properties, Configure..., Driver, Uninstall Device
- RegEdit (as Admin)

  - Change owner of `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{76A64158-CB41-11D1-8B02-00600806D9B6}` from `TrustedInstaller` to `Administrators`
  - Confirm that `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{76A64158-CB41-11D1-8B02-00600806D9B6}\TypeLib` Default value is `{565783C6-CB41-11D1-8B02-00600806D9B6}`   - Change `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{76A64158-CB41-11D1-8B02-00600806D9B6}\InProcServer32\ThreadingModel` from `Apartment` to `Both`
  - Add `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{76A64158-CB41-11D1-8B02-00600806D9B6}\AppID` = `{76A64158-CB41-11D1-8B02-00600806D9B6}`
  - Add `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\AppID\{76A64158-CB41-11D1-8B02-00600806D9B6}` Subkey
  - Add empty string value `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\AppID\{76A64158-CB41-11D1-8B02-00600806D9B6}\DllSurrogate`
- After doing all of this, found https://wiki.abiquo.com/display/ABI26/Hyper-V+Cloud+Node+Configuration, where they automate all of the above in a [Powershell Script](https://wiki.abiquo.com/download/attachments/23399766/change_registry.ps1?version=1&modificationDate=1375257230000&api=v2) and [Registry Import file](https://wiki.abiquo.com/download/attachments/23399766/hypervconfig.reg?version=1&modificationDate=1373994696000&api=v2)

  - Download and run the script to ensure I didn't mess anything up.
  - (Other options don't apply to Windows 10 Pro, or running Hyper-V locally, or when Hyper-V hasn't been installed yet.)
- [Reboot]
- Reinstall Hyper-V using Windows Features
- [Reboot]

Comment: I found https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/canitpro/2012/09/11/default-file-locations-in-hyper-v/, and I have renamed the existing Hyper-V folders.  I am going to reinstall and see if anything is remembered.  However, if there are still remembered settings, I'll be back here looking for more direction.

Comment: Nope - Uninstalled Hyper-V, renamed all associated Hyper-V folders, reinstalled Hyper-V, Quick Create the Ubuntu environment, try to start up, and... same error :-(

Comment: How did you uninstall HyperV? It is an optional feature and can be enabled and disabled in the Windows Optional Features dialog on the desktop OS versions.

Comment: Perhaps you should be asking about the actual problem instead.

Comment: I asked about the actual problem in [this SO posting, which also has a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55346545/win10-pro-hyper-v-cannot-start-any-machines-failed-to-power-on-system-cannot), so this one is specifically reserved to only resetting Hyper-V, which others have also asked for in the past (but got answers regarding their specific issue, which didn't help me at all).

Comment: @music2myear, I used the Windows Features to enable and disable Hyper-V, but if you have VMs registered when you turn Hyper-V off, when you turn it on again, the VMs are still there.  In my case, renaming the folders successfully removes the VMs previously registered, but does not correct the underlying problem that prevents me from successfully starting any VMs.

Comment: The reason why I'm awarding 100 bounty for this is because I've seen this question before, and why the OP got an answer that helped him, the answer didn't actually answer his question, and it didn't answer mine either.

Comment: See the registry-cleaning method at [Removing the ghost Hyper-V vNic adapter](https://cloudtidings.com/2013/11/20/removing-the-ghost-hyper-v-vnic-adapter-when-using-converged-networks-after-in-place-upgrade-to-w2012r2/).  Also see this [TechNET script](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Completely-remove-Hyper-V-a4aecb6c) and its associated article at [Completely remove Hyper-V Virtual Machines](http://thesccm.com/completely-remove-hyper-v-virtual-machines/).

Comment: The question you asked on Stack Overflow is off-topic over there. That’s also why it’s down-voted.

Comment: @Daniel-B Thank you for the reminder.  I'm a programmer, and so SO is my #1 stop for most problems, and I forgot that it's off-topic over there.  Still a "Off-topic, post to SuperUser.com instead" would have been useful rather than completely useless.  A useful comment would have prevented the bounty.  If SO had a method for abandoning/reposting to a more suitable forum, that would be great also, especially now that I put a bounty on it...?

Comment: @daniel-b I have voted the post on SO to be closed, and will request migration to here once the bounty is complete, because it is a different, but related post to this one.

Comment: Did you have the chance to look at my comment above?

Comment: @pimp-juice-it, I have previously run these steps, but for the sake of completeness (and because of, well, you know, Microsoft), I'll try the steps again, and maybe this time they will produce the results I'm looking for.  I'll report back with the results.

Comment: @pimp-juice-it, as suspected, while this allows me to uninstall Hyper-V (which I could not do about 3 weeks ago because of problems with a corrupted DISM), these steps do not actually reset the Hyper-V settings.  The virtual machines that were in place still exist in the associated Hyper-V folders, and the setting which is causing my real problem (“failed to power on: system cannot find the path specified”) still persists.  Thanks for the try, though.

Comment: @Dan - No worries, look over the resources per HarryMC and his suggestions, etc. above then as the solution may be in there. I've cleaned my comments since you confirm they did not help resolve.

Comment: @harrymc, unfortunately, uninstalling/reinstalling Hyper-V following the steps you offered did not result in any change to the situation.  The system is still using a path to _something_ that it wasn't using before, and it's this path that is pointing to the wrong location.  The VM that I downloaded expressly for the purpose of testing this error still generates the same error when trying to start up, after uninstall/reinstall.

Comment: Have a look in the registry at the keys `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\VM*`, to see if any are left after uninstalling Hyper-V. Some more registry settings are listed in [this article](https://wiki.abiquo.com/display/ABI26/Hyper-V+Manual+Registry+Configuration).

Comment: @harrymc, wow, that article is a seriously deep dive into the registry.  Well, I've gotta make this work, so wish me luck.  If this is the answer, then it goes a long way to explain why the question "how do I completely reset Hyper-V" hasn't been fully answered.  I'm planning this SU post to become the answer if it works...

Comment: Yes, too many registry keys in that article to list in a comment. If this works, I'll roll everything up in an answer.

Comment: @harrymc, I am continuing to build my list of what doesn't work, and unfortunately, following those instructions didn't help.  I will update the question to include what steps I have taken, for the benefit of all involved.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks to all who tried to help, but I have since abandoned this entirely. I have purchased a new machine, which I will be installing a new Windows 10 environment onto, and will start Hyper-V completely from scratch on that box, then after confirming that Hyper-V functions correctly, I will import my VMs to there.

Comment: While I entirely agree that this answer is a horrible answer, and Microsoft really does need to fix this (because "you're screwed, dude, buy a new machine" is never an answer) realize that I started searching on March 16th, and gave up on April 10th.  That was almost a month of hand-wringing and searching with no solution in sight, and this was only last year... :-(

Comment: :( I wish someone posts a better solution to this

Comment: Why didn't you just reinstall windows?

Comment: Largely because of my distrust with recovering every functional installation of all software installed over the previous 15 years using that OS installation (yes, it really had ben that long.)  Once I had a new box, I could use the new OS install, and ensure that nothing was without a backup.  Then, reinstallation was possible with no risk of data loss.

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure you just delete the configs and the dir content.

You can force it with dism

dism /online /Disable-Feature  /FeatureName:Microsoft-Hyper-V

then just

dism /online /Enable-Feature  /FeatureName:Microsoft-Hyper-V

Comment: Thanks, but no, this isn't the answer.  I have tried all 3 routes to installing/uninstalling Hyper-V (using Windows Features, using Powershell, and using dism), deleting all pertinent files/folders after each uninstall, and while Hyper-V installs/uninstalls "fine", there are still settings *somewhere* that aren't getting reset.

Comment: Thanks this not only worked for me but for some reason cut down Hyper-V's memory utilization down to half. I went from 11GB memory usage on a cold system startup down to only 4GB.